# How to filter by String in Objectify

Tags: string, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Here is my problem

```
String text = "I am here"
resutl = ofy().load().type(M.class).filter("good = "+text).first().now();
```

Since `text` contains space, how do I pass it to Objectify? Do I place it in single quotes? double quotes? what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `filter()` method takes two parameters:

```
ofy().load().type(M.class).filter("good =", text).first().now();
```

There is no need to escape the value.

Answer (score 0):

`ofy().load().type(M.class).filter("good",text).first().now()`

There is no need for "=". It is a default operator.